# Get the count per date of first logged in

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

I have a table containing the logging of a web app which tracks when people log in. An example of my table is:

```
| user_id | date_time        |
+---------+------------------+
|    0033 | 2012-11-22 10:33 | <- first login of 0033 on 2012-11-22
|    0034 | 2012-11-22 10:38 | <- first login of 0034 on 2012-11-22
|    0052 | 2012-11-22 10:43 | <- first login of 0052 on 2012-11-22
|    0052 | 2012-11-23 09:23 |
|    0066 | 2012-11-23 15:58 | <- first login of 0066 on 2012-11-23
|    0033 | 2012-11-23 16:14 |
```

The thing I want is a table with the amount of people that logged in for the first time on each date, i.e.:

```
| count | date       |
+-------+------------+
|     3 | 2012-11-22 | <- there were 3 users that logged in for the first time on 2012-11-22
|     1 | 2012-11-23 |
```

I know I can get the date only, by doing

```
SELECT DATE(`date_time`) AS `date`
FROM `logging`
GROUP BY `date`
ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

I would like to get the second table in one query, I know it's possible, I just don't know how. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an uncorrelated subquery to get the first login date for every user and then group those dates together to get the number of first logins per day.

```
SELECT dd, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT MIN(DATE(`date_time`)) AS dd
    FROM `logging`
    GROUP BY `user_id`) a
GROUP BY dd
ORDER BY dd;
```

[`Demo`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb004/2)

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of logins per day, for user_ids that have do not have a previous login record:

```
select  DATE(`date_time`) as `date`,
        count(user_id)
from    `logging` l1
where   user_id not in (
        select user_id from `logging` l2 where l1.user_id = l2.user_id and l2.date_time < l1.date_time)
group by DATE(`date_time`)
```

Comment: Your sub query will perform pretty badly knowing that there will be much more logins than users.

Comment: This works too, but as @Jack said, it takes long on big logs. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score -1):

I think you need this:

```
SELECT count(1) ,
       DATE(`date_time`) 
from my_table
group by DATE(`date_time`)
```

If you need users which had been logged in day wise

```
Select 

user_id, `date_time` from my_table group by DATE(`date_time`), user_id
```

Comment: This shows all logins for that day, not just the first time someone logs in

Comment: Try the SECOND query, It will result in the user with their first login in that day